# Decoding big text input: potential concurrency bugs?

Tags: java, thread-safety, concurrency, guava

The code here will be directly pasted from [this project](https://github.com/fge/largetext). Quick summary: it is related to a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22017480/1093528).

So, basically, all the code below aims to implement `CharSequence` over a large text file, within the limitation of `CharSequence` itself (that is, up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` chars). All the code below is extracted from [the same package](https://github.com/fge/largetext/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/largetext/load).

The process is as follows:

- a `TextDecoder` is issued for one file which (supposedly) contains text; it will decode byte sequences into char sequences;
- it instantiates one instance of a `DecodingStatus`; this class will keep track of how many characters were successfully decoded so far, and if necessary will report an error instead;
- processes "waiting" for a given amount of characters will create a `CharWaiter` instance; they will be queues into the `DecoderStatus` only if their requirement (character offset) has not been meant;
- should a decoding error happen, the `DecodingStatus` instance will terminate all `CharWaiter`s for an instance.

OK; so, first things first: the code works and is mostly tested; my problem is that it is ugly. In particular, in `DecodingStatus`, all methods *except one* are synchronized. Also, error "recovery" code is duplicated in several places.

How can I improve upon this code? In particular, can I avoid making (nearly) all methods in `DecodingStatus` `synchronized`? Can I avoid duplicating error checking?

First, the `CharWaiter`:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

/**
 * A waiter on a number of available characters in a {@link TextDecoder}
 *
 * <p>When it is woken up, it will check for the status of the operation; it
 * will throw a {@link RuntimeException} if the decoding operation fails, or it
 * has waited to more characters than what is actually available.</p>
 *
 * <p>It implements {@link Comparable} since instances of this class are used in
 * a {@link PriorityQueue}.</p>
 *
 * <p>Inspired from <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055231/1093528">this
 * StackOverflow answer</a>.</p>
 *
 * @see DecodingStatus
 * @see TextDecoder#needChars(int)
 */
final class CharWaiter
    implements Comparable<CharWaiter>
{
    private final int required;
    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    private int nrChars = 0;
    private IOException exception = null;

    CharWaiter(final int required)
    {
        if (required < 0)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(required);
        this.required = required;
    }

    void setNrChars(final int nrChars)
    {
        this.nrChars = nrChars;
    }

    void setException(final IOException exception)
    {
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    int getRequired()
    {
        return required;
    }

    void await()
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        latch.await();
        if (exception != null)
            throw new RuntimeException("decoding error", exception);
        if (nrChars < required)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(required);
    }

    void wakeUp()
    {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@Nonnull final CharWaiter o)
    {
        return Integer.compare(required, o.required);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "waiting for " + required + " character(s)";
    }
}
```

Then, the `DecodingStatus`:

```
import javax.annotation.concurrent.ThreadSafe;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

/**
 * The watchdog class for a text decoding operation
 *
 * <p>This class takes care of {@link CharWaiter}s and callers to {@link
 * TextDecoder#getTotalChars()}.</p>
 *
 * <p>The decoding process in {@link TextDecoder} will update the internal
 * status of this object when the decoding operation makes progress; on an
 * update, this class will wake up the relevant waiters.</p>
 *
 * <p>In the event of an error, all waiters are woken up.</p>
 *
 * @see CharWaiter
 */
@ThreadSafe
final class DecodingStatus
{
    private boolean finished = false;
    private int nrChars = -1;
    private IOException exception = null;
    private final Queue<CharWaiter> waiters = new PriorityQueue<>();
    private final CountDownLatch endLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    synchronized boolean addWaiter(final CharWaiter waiter)
    {
        if (exception != null)
            throw new RuntimeException("decoding error", exception);
        final int required = waiter.getRequired();
        if (required <= nrChars)
            return false;
        if (!finished) {
            waiters.add(waiter);
            return true;
        }
        if (required > nrChars)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(required);
        return false;
    }

    synchronized void setNrChars(final int nrChars)
    {
        this.nrChars = nrChars;
        CharWaiter waiter;
        while (!waiters.isEmpty()) {
            waiter = waiters.peek();
            if (waiter.getRequired() > nrChars)
                break;
            waiter.setNrChars(nrChars);
            waiters.remove().wakeUp();
        }
    }

    synchronized void setFailed(final IOException exception)
    {
        this.exception = exception;
        final List<CharWaiter> list = new ArrayList<>(waiters);
        waiters.clear();
        for (final CharWaiter waiter: list) {
            waiter.setException(exception);
            waiter.wakeUp();
        }
        endLatch.countDown();
    }

    synchronized void setFinished(final int nrChars)
    {
        finished = true;
        this.nrChars = nrChars;
        final List<CharWaiter> list = new ArrayList<>(waiters);
        waiters.clear();
        for (final CharWaiter waiter: list) {
            waiter.setNrChars(nrChars);
            waiter.wakeUp();
        }
        endLatch.countDown();
    }

    int getTotalSize()
    {
        try {
            endLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException("interrupted", e);
        }
        if (exception != null)
            throw new RuntimeException("decoding error", exception);
        return nrChars;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized String toString()
    {
        if (exception != null)
            return "decoding error after reading " + nrChars + " character(s)";
        return "currently decoded: " + nrChars + " character(s); finished: "
            + finished;
    }
}
```

And finally, the `TextDecoder`:

```
import com.github.fge.largetext.LargeText;
import com.github.fge.largetext.LargeTextFactory;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
import com.google.common.collect.RangeMap;
import com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeMap;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;

import javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy;
import javax.annotation.concurrent.ThreadSafe;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CoderResult;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;


/**
 * Text file decoder
 *
 * <p>This is the first core class of this package (the second is {@link
 * TextLoader}. Its role is to decode a text file chunk by chunk. The size of
 * chunks to use is determined when you build your {@link LargeTextFactory}.</p>
 *
 * <p>{@link LargeText} will call upon this class to obtain a {@link TextRange}
 * (or a list of them) containing the character at a given index (or the range
 * of characters), by using the methods {@link #getRange(int)} and {@link
 * #getRanges(com.google.common.collect.Range)} respectively.</p>
 *
 * <p>These methods are blocking, but they <em>do not</em> throw {@link
 * InterruptedException}; if an interruption occurs, these methods reset the
 * thread interruption status and throw the appropriate {@link
 * RuntimeException} (for instance, an {@link ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException} if
 * the requested offset exceeds the number of characters in the file).</p>
 *
 * <p>Implementation note: this class uses a <em>single threaded</em> {@link
 * ExecutorService} to perform the decoding operation. Decoding is not done in
 * parallel, and cannot be, since it is not guaranteeed that a byte mapping can
 * be decoded exactly to a character sequence (for instance, using UTF-8, the
 * end of the mapping may contain one byte only of a three-byte sequence).</p>
 *
 * @see DecodingStatus
 */
@ThreadSafe
public final class TextDecoder
    implements Closeable
{
    private static final ThreadFactory THREAD_FACTORY
        = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).build();

    private final ExecutorService executor
        = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(THREAD_FACTORY);

    private final DecodingStatus status = new DecodingStatus();

    @GuardedBy("ranges")
    private final RangeMap<Integer, TextRange> ranges = TreeRangeMap.create();

    private final FileChannel channel;
    private final Charset charset;
    private final long fileSize;
    private final long targetMapSize;

    /**
     * Constructor; don't use directly!
     *
     * @param channel the {@link FileChannel} to the target file
     * @param charset the character encoding to use
     * @param targetMapSize the target byte mapping size
     * @throws IOException error obtaining information on the channel
     */
    public TextDecoder(final FileChannel channel, final Charset charset,
        final long targetMapSize)
        throws IOException
    {
        this.channel = channel;
        fileSize = channel.size();
        this.targetMapSize = targetMapSize;
        this.charset = charset;
        executor.submit(decodingTask());
    }

    /**
     * Return the appropriate text range containing the character at the given
     * offset
     *
     * @param charOffset the offset
     * @return the appropriate {@link TextRange}
     * @throws RuntimeException method has been interrupted, or a decoding error
     * has occurred
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException offset requested is out of range
     */
    public TextRange getRange(final int charOffset)
    {
        try {
            needChars(charOffset + 1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted", e);
        }
        synchronized (ranges) {
            return ranges.get(charOffset);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return an ordered iterable of text ranges covering the requested range
     *
     * @param range  the range
     * @return the appropriate list of text ranges
     * @throws RuntimeException method has been interrupted, or a decoding error
     * has occurred
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException range is out of bounds for this
     * decoder
     */
    public List<TextRange> getRanges(final Range<Integer> range)
    {
        try {
            needChars(range.upperEndpoint());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted", e);
        }
        final Collection<TextRange> ret;
        synchronized (ranges) {
            ret = ranges.subRangeMap(range).asMapOfRanges().values();
        }
        return ImmutableList.copyOf(ret);
    }

    /**
     * Return the total number of characters in this decoder
     *
     * <p>This method sleeps until the decoding operation finishes (either
     * successfully or with an error).</p>
     *
     * @return the total number of characters
     * @throws RuntimeException method has been interrupted, or a decoding error
     * has occurred
     *
     * @see DecodingStatus#getTotalSize()
     */
    public int getTotalChars()
    {
        return status.getTotalSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
        throws IOException
    {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private void needChars(final int needed)
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        final CharWaiter waiter = new CharWaiter(needed);
        if (status.addWaiter(waiter))
            waiter.await();
    }

    // TODO: move to another class?
    private Runnable decodingTask()
    {
        return new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                final CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder()
                    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
                    .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
                final CharBuffer charMap
                    = CharBuffer.allocate((int) targetMapSize);

                long byteOffset = 0L;
                int charOffset = 0;
                TextRange range;

                while (byteOffset < fileSize) {
                    try {
                        range = nextRange(byteOffset, charOffset, decoder,
                            charMap);
                        if (range.getByteRange().isEmpty())
                            throw new IOException("unable to read file as text "
                                + "starting from byte offset " + byteOffset);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        status.setFailed(e);
                        break;
                    }
                    byteOffset = range.getByteRange().upperEndpoint();
                    charOffset = range.getCharRange().upperEndpoint();
                    status.setNrChars(charOffset);
                    synchronized (ranges) {
                        ranges.put(range.getCharRange(), range);
                    }
                }
                status.setFinished(charOffset);
            }

        };
    }

    private TextRange nextRange(final long byteOffset, final int charOffset,
        final CharsetDecoder decoder, final CharBuffer charMap)
        throws IOException
    {
        long nrBytes = Math.min(targetMapSize, fileSize - byteOffset);

        final MappedByteBuffer byteMap
            = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, byteOffset, nrBytes);

        charMap.rewind();
        decoder.reset();

        final CoderResult result = decoder.decode(byteMap, charMap, true);

        // FIXME
        if (result.isUnmappable())
            result.throwException();

        /*
         * Incomplete byte sequence: in this case, the mapping position reflects
         * what was actually read; change the mapping size
         */
        if (result.isMalformed())
            nrBytes = (long) byteMap.position();

        return new TextRange(byteOffset, nrBytes, charOffset,
            charMap.position());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `TextRandge` could be declared inside the loop and could be `final`:

   > ```
   > TextRange range;
   >
   > while (byteOffset < fileSize) {
   > ```

   The same is true for `waiter` here:

   > ```
   > CharWaiter waiter;
   > while (!waiters.isEmpty()) {
   >     waiter = waiters.peek();
   > ```

   (*Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*)
2. I'd rename this to `createDecodingTask`:

   > ```
   > // TODO: move to another class?
   > private Runnable decodingTask()
   > ```

   From *Clean Code, Chapter 2: Meaningful Names*:

   > **Method Names**
   >
   > Methods should have verb or verb phrase names like `postPayment`, `deletePage`, or `save`.
   >   [...]
3. For the `TODO` comment above: I'm usually working with a lot smaller classes than 240 lines, I'd move it to another class. It makes testing easier.
4. I'd wait here a little bit with `executor.awaitTermination` and check its return value.

   > ```
   > @Override
   > public void close()
   >     throws IOException
   > {
   >     executor.shutdown();
   > }
   > ```

   I see that the code uses daemon threads but if the application doesn't stop entirely, just closes the `TextDecoder` it may have some threads running in the background needlessly and without any notice. Failing early usually helps preventing bigger bugs/shutdowns.
5. Moving this code to another class and passing an `Executor` to the constructor would help testing also (probably with a [current thread executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6581188/843804)):

   > ```
   > private static final ThreadFactory THREAD_FACTORY
   >     = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).build();
   >
   > private final ExecutorService executor
   >     = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(THREAD_FACTORY);
   > ```

   It would separate the concerns, you could test the parts isolated.
6. Starting another thread/Runnable from the constructor [smells a little bit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/48941/36726). It looks safe as its the last call in the constructor but I'd still try to avoid that.
7. You could move this logic to a `checkException` method, it's used twice:

   > ```
   > if (exception != null)
   >     throw new RuntimeException("decoding error", exception);
   > ```
8. The code already uses Guava, so I'd consider using `Preconditions.checkArgument` here (although it throws `IllegalArgumentException`):

   > ```
   > if (required < 0)
   >     throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(required);
   > ```
9. A more descriptive name than `nrChars` (`loadedChars`, `readChars`, `decodedChars`?) and a named constants for `-1` (with a descriptive name) would help readers here:

   > ```
   > private int nrChars = -1;
   > ```
10. I would be a little bit more defensive here and check that the `nrChars` parameter's value is higher than the field's value:

    > ```
    > synchronized void setNrChars(final int nrChars)
    > {
    >     this.nrChars = nrChars;
    > ```

    (*The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.)
11. The following is used more than once, I'd create a method for it:

    > ```
    > final List<CharWaiter> list = new ArrayList<>(waiters);
    > waiters.clear();
    > ```
12. I don't think that `DecodingStatus` is thread-safe. Reading of `nrChars` should be also in a synchronized block (in `getTotalSize()`).

    > [...] synchronization has no effect unless both read and write operations are synchronized.

    Source: *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data*

    > Locking is not just about mutual exclusion; it is also about memory visibility.
    >   To ensure that all threads see the most up-to-date values of shared mutable 
    >   variables, the reading and writing threads must synchronize on a common lock.

    Source: *Java Concurrency in Practice, 3.1.3. Locking and Visibility*.

Comment: As to point 1, I prefer it this way... Minimizing the scope is all good all well, but I prefer to declare my variables _out_ of the loop in this case.

Comment: Point 8: no! I implement `CharSequence` here, so I need to throw this exception